# Finding integers $m,n$ such that $(m-n)^2=4mn/(m+n-1)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find all the integer numbers (m, n) which satisfy:
$(m-n)^2=4mn/(m+n-1)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, note that $m+n\neq 1$.

One can see that $(m^2+n^2-2mn)(m+n-1)=4mn$. It implies that $m^3+n^3-m^2n-n^2m-n^2-m^2+2mn=4mn$ and so $(m+n)(m^2+n^2-mn)+-mn(m+n)-(m+n)^2=0$. We can conclude that $(m+n)((m-n)^2-(m+n))=0$. Thus $m+n=0$ or $(m-n)^2-(m+n)=0$.

Assume that $m \geq n$. So $m=n+k$ where $k\in \mathbb N$ and $k>1$. Thus, $k^2=2n+k$ and so $k(k-1)/2=n$. We can conclude that $(m,n)=(\frac{k(k+1)}{2},\frac{k(k-1)}{2})$